# Fechar modal ao atualizar página após um INSERT

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, modal, sql-insert

procurei em todos os cantos da internet mas não consegui encontrar nada igual ao meu problema. Tenho um formulário de cadastro que após fazer o INSERT no banco de dados mostra uma janela modal e dentro dela uma mensagem de sucesso ou de erro junto com um botão de "OK". Isso funciona perfeitamente, apertando OK ele fecha a modal e exibe novamente a página de cadastro. O meu problema é que se o usuário antes de aperta "OK" der um "F5" é mostrada a caixa de diálogo "Confirmar reenvio de formulário" e se clicar em "Continuar" ele duplica o INSERT e consequentemente o cadastro no banco.

[image: Reenvio de formulário]

Segue o código resumido do PHP:

```html
if (isset($_POST['cadastrar'])) {

<!-- aqui vão os requires dos includes com os dados do banco-->

$sql = "INSERT";

$resultado mysqli_query($conexao, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($conexao));

$linhas = mysqli_affected_rows($conexao);

if($linhas > 0){

$mensagem = "Seu cadastro foi feito com sucesso!";

} else {

$mensagem = "Erro ao cadastrar!";

}

<!-- aqui vai o require include de desconexão-->

<!--o código abaixo chama a janela modal-->

?><script>$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});</script>
<?php

}

?>
```

Abaixo segue o código da janela modal:

```html
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Mensagem:</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p><?php echo"$mensagem"; ?></p> <!--exibe a mensagem de erro ou sucesso-->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Abaixo os scripts para buscar os comandos do bootstrap e jquery:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <!--Banco de comandos para executar a janela modal-->
```

Então basicamente o que eu gostaria era que se apessoa teclasse F5 durante a exibição da janela modal, a conexão com o banco fosse encerrada e simplesmente mostrasse a página de cadastro e a modal sumisse. Tentei colocar um `header ("Location:")` antes do javascript que exibe a modal, para ele redirecionar a página, porém ele redireciona mas não exibe a modal. Já vi sites em que isso funciona, você faz o cadastro e é mostrada a modal, da F5 e a modal fecha e não pede reenvio de formulário.

Todo o código está em um mesmo aquivo, se precisarem de mais algum dado é só pedir. Valeu galera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, solução mais pratica, testa aí, fiz rapidinho sem testar. Basicamente, no post se ocorre o insert ou o erro, haverá o location com envio do get, se a página carregar e tiver o get abre o modal.

Lance meio arcaico, mas, de acordo com o que precisa.

```
<?php   
    if (isset($_POST['cadastrar']))
    {
        $sql = "INSERT";
        $resultado mysqli_query($conexao, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($conexao));
        $linhas = mysqli_affected_rows($conexao);

        if($linhas > 0)
        {

            //Redireciona e envia um GET
            echo 
            "
                <script>
                    location.href = 'arquivo.php?action=ok';
                </script>
            ";
        }
        else
        {

            //Redireciona e envia um GET
            echo 
            "
                <script>
                    location.href = 'arquivo.php?action=erro';
                </script>
            ";
        }
    }

    //Verifica se existe GET action
        if (isset($_GET['action']))
        {
            if($_GET['action'] =='ok'){

                $mensagem = "Seu cadastro foi feito com sucesso!";

            } else {

                $mensagem = "Erro ao cadastrar!";
            }
            echo 
            "
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $('#myModal').modal('show');
                    });
                </script>
            ";
        }
?>
```

Comment: Realmente o que eu precisava brother, funcionou direitinho! Unica adaptação que fiz foi clocar um evento onclick no botão da modal que redirecionava para a mesma página, pois a variável "action" ainda ficava ativa e eu tinha uma função de pesquisa nessa página, ou seja, a modal aparecia ao apertar o botão "Pesquisar". Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Bom na verdade o seu problema está no comportamento do navegador ao pressionar a tecla F5 ou mesmo o botão atualizar. Por padrão os navegadores refazem a última operação executada, que no seu caso é um POST para o servidor.

Analisando superficialmente esse problema, a forma mais fácil de impedir essa situação seria logo após realizar seu comando SQL, redirecionar o usuário para um outro arquivo só com as informações a serem exibidas, pois ao atualizar essa página, não teria efeito nenhum no banco de dados. Usando o seu próprio código, ficaria assim:

Arquivo post.php:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['cadastrar'])) {

        <!-- aqui vão os requires dos includes com os dados do banco-->

        $sql = "INSERT";

        $resultado mysqli_query($conexao, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($conexao));

        $linhas = mysqli_affected_rows($conexao);

        <!-- aqui vai o require include de desconexão-->

        header('Location: exibe.php?linhas=' . $linhas);
    } else {
        echo 'Parâmetros incorretos.'
    }
?>
```

Arquivo exibe.php

```
<?php
    $linhas = $_GET['linhas'];

    if($linhas > 0){
        $mensagem = "Seu cadastro foi feito com sucesso!";
    } else {
        $mensagem = "Erro ao cadastrar!";
    }

    <!--o código abaixo chama a janela modal-->

?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Seu exemplo ficou bem parecido com o do sNniffer e creio que deve funcionar, porém a passagem da variável $linhas para o outro arquivo não funcionou da forma que você colocou. De qualquer forma pode ajudar muita gente. Obrigado!

Comment: Você tem razão!  Fiz uma edição na resposta pois eu deveria ter pego a variável via GET. Agora está ok.